# Get value from SQL database using HTTPClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to get a value from a SQL database using a C# Forms application through a .net core Web API; so far I have the code below. What do I do next? If I want to get say `CustomerID`?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:21716/");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Customers").Result;
var cust = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Customer>>().Result;
```

This is my first time using `HttpClient` and I'm not sure if I'm doing this right?

I have a couple of questions...

1. Is this the right way to do this?
2. Do I have to do the above every time I want to get data from my database?

The database was created with EF Core 2.0 model, controllers and context using code-first method.

There isn't very much on Core 2.0 so, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: What happens when you run that code? What is the value of `cust`? What is the purpose of hiding the database behind a Web API for your application? In its current state this question is very broad. You are leaving a lot out -- such as the actual database access code and API implementation. We can only guess about how the API is supposed to behave. But 1) it looks _basically_ correct 2) probably, yes.

Comment: 2. [Don't create a new instance of HttpClient every time.](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: First. Thanks @marc_s. Second, the value of cust is the async response customer which I think is a list of the customer table. The API is effectively, just a data connection between the client (windows form application) and the database. (Think of it as an MVC application, but more abstract) I can't post the whole solution, it's made up of 6 projects. All I'm looking for is to get a single value right now of CustomerID

Comment: And no, the code above doesn't produce anything, That's the next step, to get CustomerID from Customer table, but I don't know how to. The code works fine because I can get all the table data by simply doing the below. var cust = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Customer>>().Result; DataGridView1.DatSource = cust;